# Creating a macro to Unhide worksheets and Clear Used Rows, Resetting the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 52 sheet workbook that needs to be reset after the file is saved as a copy.
I have the `UnHide` part figured out, but I can't seem to figure out the `Clearcontents`.

On many Worksheets, not all, in `row A` there is a string "State Requires All License Verifications"
It is in a variable row, between 6 and 12.  Starting with `ws2` I want to find the string and clear the rows below it. Column `range A:H`

Then Check the next worksheet.

I have this so far..

```
Sub UnhideAllSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rowNum As Long
Dim stateReg As String

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    If ws.Visible Then
     'Activate sheet
     ws.Activate

    'Look for String "State Requires All License Verifications"
        Set stateReq = .Find(what:="State Requires All License Verifications")

    'Null find quits loop
        If Not stateReq Is Nothing Then
        rowNum = stateReq.Row
        End If

    'Clear all Used rows after String(stateReq)

        With Sheets(ws)
            Intersect(.Range(.Rows(rowNum + 1), .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count)), .Range("A:H")).ClearContents
        End With

     'Select and Zoom to A1 upon leaving the worksheet

        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1

    End If

Next ws

'Jump back to the first worksheet "Information"
Sheets("Information").Select
Range("E2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to me looping each sheet (currentWS) in the Worksheets collection and then `currentWS.Cells.Delete` ought to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Not sure where you got stuck.

I have assumed the string is in column A and that A is also a reliable indicator of the last used row (so may need changing).

Also no need to activate the sheet.

```
Sub UnhideAllSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rowNum As Long
Dim stateReg As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Set stateReg = ws.Columns(1).Find(what:="State Requires All License Verifications", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not stateReg Is Nothing Then
        Range(stateReg.Offset(1), ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 8).ClearContents
    End If
Next ws

'Jump back to the first worksheet "Information"
Application.Goto Sheets("Information").Range("E2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Allways forget about the `Application.GoTo`. + One

Comment: Ok, I have tried both of the scripts, and they work equally well at clearing the forms, BUT they also clear the Target Script.  I even added the offset(2) instead of (1) and I still loose the Target.

Comment: That could only happen if there is nothing underneat that text in column A.

Comment: I think that the .End(xlUp) is carrying the range back up to included the Target Script.  I think that I need to offset the row (1) after the xlUp, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
Sub Fresh_Slate()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Found As Range
Dim Target As String
Dim lr As Long

Target = "State Requires All License Verifications"

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then          'You can add sheets to ignore here

        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Set Found = ws.Cells.Find(Target)

        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            'Assuming Column A on each sheet is a good indicator of the last used row in range
            lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Row + 1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, 8)).ClearContents
        End If

        Set Found = Nothing
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to not clear the Conditional Formatting?  I like my Zebra stripes!  Other wise it is a very clean solution, I appreciate the help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb178828(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: You are right, thank you for clearing that up.  A prior mistake cause the format change.  I am all good now..!  Thanks for the help.